Shortcut for annotations in Spring
I have several methods with quite similar annotations. I want to extract common parts.
For example I have this:
    @ApiResponse(
            description = "Some description",
            responseCode = "200",
            content = @Content(
                    mediaType = "application/json",
                    schema = @Schema(
                            contains = SomeClass.class
                    )
            ))

I want to simplify it to:
    @MyApiResponse(
            description = "Some description",
            type = SomeClass.class
    )

I found @AliasFor annotation that helps with simple cases like description, but if I need to do more complex transformation I have no solution.
Here example of what I got for now:
    @ApiResponse(
            responseCode = "200"
    )
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface MyApiResponse {
        @AliasFor(
                attribute = "description",
                annotation = ApiResponse.class
        )
        String description();

        Class<?> type();
    }

My question: is there any kind of processor or transformer that I can implement to fill content attribute?
If there is no available solution I'm ready to implement it myself. In this case what class responsible for @AliasFor processing?
